# Minimum difference of sums

Tags: algorithms, optimization, time-complexity, asymptotics

So hey, I've recently found this problem online and I tried hard to solve but couldn't found an efficient solution. The problem statement is:

Given and two integers $n$ and $k$ and an array $A$ containing $n$ pairs of integers of the form $(a, b)$ and $d$ defined as $d = |\sum_{x \in E} x[1] -x[0]| $ where is $E$ is a subset of $A$ containing exactly $k$ elements. Find the minimum value of $d$.

To illustrate the problem, consider $n = 3$, $k = 2$,  $A = [(2, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)]$.

The minimum value of $d$ is $0$. We can pick $E = [(1, 2), (2, 1)]$ containing $k = 2$ values of $A$ then $d = |(1 - 2) + (2 - 1)| = |0| = 0$.

I tried to solve this problem but only came up with the brute force solution which is terrible in terms of time complexity.

> How can one solve this problem efficiently ?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem.  This looks like a duplicate of https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/10981/755 -- what do others think?  See also https://mathoverflow.net/q/229344/37212.

Comment: Can you add attribution for where you encountered the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unable to add comments but I think this problem can be simplified to:

```
B = []
for pair in A:
    B.append(pair[0] - pair[1])

min_sum(B, k)
```

`min_sum` returns k elements that add up to give the smallest number possible (absolute value). This (at least to me) feels easier to work with.

Comment: And this in turn is almost the subset sum problem.

Comment: Can you explain how to reduce to subset sum problem ?

Comment: @Noctisark Using Izaan's notation, the subset sum problem can be formulated as "Is any of min_sum(B, 1), ...,min_sum(B, N) equal to zero?".

Comment: I actually thought about it and said it would likely timeout, thanks for the answer, really :).